# WPF Bind TextBox.Text to a property of the item bound to the SelectedItem of a ComboBox

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, textbox, selecteditem

I have a combobox whose itemssource is a collection of objects of my domain model.  One of the properties of that object is 'Amount'
How do I bind the 'Amount' property of the SelectedItem of the combobox to the text of a texdtbox?

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to do it in xaml is to use a binding with a element name.

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" x:Name="ComboBox"></ComboBox>
 <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.Amount}"></TextBox>
```

You set a x:name at the combobox and use this name to bind the text box.

If you use a MVVM pattern you should think about binding the selected item of the combobox to your viewModel and then bind the textbox to this property of your viewModel.